# VBA regex - getting matches from multiple lines

Tags: regex, vba

Provided that I have the following text:

```
55,8%(1) – 3426 bytes used from 6kB
58,1%(2) – 3572 bytes used from 6kB
```

I would like to use the following pattern:

```
^(\d\d,\d)(?:%\(\d\) . )(\d{3,4})(?: )(bytes)(?: used from )(\d{1,3})(?:kB)$
```

It returns matches only from the second line. But **I want it to get matches from both lines**:
[image: debug]

Here is the code which I use:

```
Dim ramtext As String
ramtext = getTableCellText("1.7", 3, 2)

Dim regex As New RegExp
With regex
    .Pattern = "^(\d\d,\d)(?:%\(\d\) . )(\d{3,4})(?: )(bytes)(?: used from )(\d{1,3})(?:kB)$"
    .Global = 1
    .MultiLine = 1
End With


Dim matches As MatchCollection
Set matches = regex.Execute(ramtext)
```

Comment: Are you sure there are no junk chars at the start? Try adding `\W*` right after `^`. Try `"^\W*(\d\d,\d)%\(\d\) . (\d{3,4}) (bytes) used from (\d{1,3})kB$"`

Comment: Still the same. If you try this on regexr.com you'll see that the pattern itself works. And also regexr recognises both lines (you need to set multiline=true there)

Comment: Are you sure the spaces are regular? Try replacing spaces with `\s`. Try `"^(\d\d,\d)%\(\d\)\s.\s(\d{3,4})\s(bytes)\sused\sfrom\s(\d{1,3})kB$"`.

Comment: Do not copy the regex from the comment above, SO inserts garbled chars there - take it from https://regex101.com/r/JVOFIj/1

Comment: I see. It works fine on regex101, though it seems to still have the same unexpected result in VBA. I guess this is related to some bug / unique behavior of VBA. The regex pattern itself is of course correctly defined, both with spaces and \s characters.

Comment: No bug in VBA, it is related to your input string only.

Comment: When debugging, check the `ramtext` exact contents. Copy it from the debugger and check at http://r12a.github.io/apps/conversion/. There must be something you did not expect. Maybe the dash is Unicode and `.` only matches a single byte.

Comment: The code works for me in Excel, using early binding like in the example and with this hardcoded: ramtext = "55,8%(1) – 3426 bytes used from 6kB" & vbNewLine & "58,1%(2) – 3572 bytes used from 6kB" ...

Comment: @Jbjstam Seems that in the document editor (outside vba) newlines are not represented with vbNewLine but with a character nr 13. Apparently they are not the same and for regexing vbnewline must be used.

Comment: Oh I see. Yes, \r is used for hard returns and \v for soft ones in Office apps, if I recall correctly. Didn't realize you were reading text from a document :) Well done figuring it out and posting it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was the following.

At the end of the first line, there is a newline character. In the document editor (outside VBA) newlines are not represented with vbNewLine, but it is a character of number 13. Those two are not the same, and for regexing vbNewLine must be used. So I had to replace it with vbNewLine.

```
ramtext = Replace(text, Chr(13), vbNewLine)
```